# System of differential equations and uniqueness and existence

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The problem:

> Let $A:\Bbb{R} \mapsto M_n (\Bbb{R})$ be continuous and suppose that there exists $L>0$
>   such that
>   $$ \| A(t)\| \leq L \; ,\; \forall t \in \Bbb{R} \; . $$
>   And let $x(t)$ be a solution of $x' =A(t) x $
>   Problem a.  Find the equation whose solution is: 
>   $$\text{given } \alpha \in \Bbb{R} \; ,\; y_{\alpha} (t)=e^{-\alpha t} x(t)\; . $$
>   Problem b. Prove the existence of values of $\alpha $ such that 
>   $$\lim_{t \to \infty} y_{\alpha} (t) $$
>   is either zero or infinity.

I have been reading [some handouts](https://www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/2250systems-de.pdf) of Prof. Grant Gustafson, which explain linear systems of differential equations; however, I still don't understand how to find the equation requested in the problem.
I also don't know how can I use the fact that the image is bounded.

How can I find the equation the problem asks for?

Edit: Following the advice on Fred's answer, I fixed the expression involving $\alpha t$ .

Comment: The boundedness of the image implies that $f(x,t) = A(t)x$ is uniformly Lipschitz in $x$. According to Picard-Lindelöf, the solution $x$ exists and is unique.

Comment: @Jonas Thank you! I’ve read already about Picard-Lindelöf, so that makes sense to me. How can I continue from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$ and $y_{\alpha} (t)=e^{-\alpha (t)} x(t)$. I think it should read  $y_{\alpha} (t)=e^{-\alpha t} x(t)$, since $ \alpha$ is a constant.

Now use the product rule to obtain:

$$y_{\alpha}' (t)=e^{- \alpha t}(A(t)-\alpha I)x(t).$$

Comment: Ooops , yes , that is what I mean

Comment: And what about the limit part of the question?